# How to join two MongoDB-collections + group?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new in MongoDB and have a problem with a query:

I have two collections:

1. Collection: "output2": with 'movieid', 'customerid', 'rating', 'date'

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9dc666d73cde2924cc0a4d"), 
    "movieid" : NumberInt(1), 
    "customerid" : NumberInt(1488844), 
    "rating" : NumberInt(3), 
    "date" : ISODate("2005-09-06T00:00:00.000+0000")
}
```

2. Collection: "movie_titles": with 'movieid', 'year', 'title'

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c9dc68ad73cde2924cd94db"), 
    "movieid" : NumberInt(1001), 
    "year" : NumberInt(2001), 
    "title" : "Blow Dry"
}
```

I have to find the average rating for each year and month, sorted by year and month in asc order, for the movie "Dinosaur Planet".

Result should looks like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(515436), 
    "year" : NumberInt(2001),
    "month" : NumberInt(10),
    "Average" : 3.0, 
    "Movietitle": "Dinosaur Planet"
}
```

I tried to solve it with different approaches, but with no result.

```
db.getCollection("output2").aggregate([ 
    {
   "$lookup":
     {
       from: "movie_titles",
       localField: "movieid",
       foreignField: "movieid",
       as: "movietitle"
     }
},

    {
        "$group": { 
            "_id": {$year: '$date'}, 
            "Average": { "$avg": "$rating" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {      
            "title": "Dinosaur Planet"
        }
    }
]);
```

Like this query. So my question is if I am on the right path or if anyone has an good idea for solving this problem?

Comment: So, I'm not sitting at your computer and neither is anyone else here other than you. Perhaps you might consider showing us what documents in the collections actually look like and what the expected result from joining the documents you show and grouping is actually supposed to look like in your mind. Showing the aggregation statement is fine, but it lacks "context" without showing some data to others for them to work with. Just a few documents in order to reproduce your expected result will be enough. No screenshots please.

Comment: Thx, I edited it. Hope the question  is better now.

Comment: How are those documents supposed to relate to each other? When I say "reproducible" I do really mean that **we** should be able to use this data you give us and return something you expect to see. So if you have `movieId` equal to `1` in one document, then the related document(s) also need to share that same value. Same goes for the other collection and `$lookup` condition. And you you mean **many** in any case instead of **just one**, then include several documents from that collection. That's how you ask a question like this here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$match` just after `$lookup` query and matching field will be `movietitle.title` and not `title` :

```
db.getCollection("output2").aggregate([ 
{
"$lookup":
 {
   from: "movie_titles",
   localField: "movieid",
   foreignField: "movieid",
   as: "movietitle"
 }
},
{
    "$match": {      
        "movietitle.title": "Dinosaur Planet"
    }
},
{
  "$unwind": "$movietitle"  
},
{
"$group": { 
    "_id": {year: '$$ROOT.movietitle.year'}, 
      "Average": { "$avg": "$rating" }
    }
}
]);
```